# Elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm confused by what is meant by elements in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

When asked the question if a set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, I would have to satisfy some criteria. One of which is that the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is in the set. How would I know what the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is?

Comment: It's a lot like the zero vector of ${\bf R}^3$, only with the obvious modification.

Comment: The zero vector of $\Bbb R^n$ (*with the usual addition and scalar multiplication rules*) is simply the $n$-tuple where every entry is zero.  For $\Bbb R^4$ that would explicitly be $(0,0,0,0)$.  An element of $\Bbb R^n$ is simply an $n$-tuple of real numbers.  For $\Bbb R^4$ specifically, that would be a $4$-tuple of the form $(x,y,z,s)$ where each of $x,y,z,s$ are each real numbers.

Comment: That $(0,0,0,0)$ is the zero vector of $\Bbb R^4$ can be proven a number of ways, but most importantly you should know the definition: the zero vector, $\text{Zero}$, satisfies the property that $\text{Zero}+u = u+\text{Zero} = u$ for all vectors $u$.  It should be clear that there can only ever be one zero vector and that $(0,0,0,0)$ satisfies this property.

Comment: ah yes! that makes so much sense, thank you!